# Does anybody know how to record/capture data into a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have for after alot of days of research found no answer, so i hope that we can find a solution here.

```
Matrix = np.random.randint(5, size=(60, 6, 6))
arr = np.random.randint(5, size=(1, 240))
arr1 = np.random.randint(5, size=(1, 240))
arr2 = np.random.randint(5, size=(1, 240))
arr3 = np.random.randint(5, size=(1, 240))
```

in the original data all the arr, arr1, arr2, arr3 consists of different data and got sizes of (1,240), but is sliced to size (1,72), kkk, vvv represents placement shifts for each iteration but with the fixed size of (1,72)
but might not be relevant to solving this case.

I have this code:

```
kkk = 3
vvv = 79
    while True:
        for i in range(len(Matrix)):
            for j in range(len(Matrix[i])):
                for z in range(len(Matrix[j])):
                    pass
                    Matrix2 = np.concatenate((arr[kkk:vvv], arr1[kkk:vvv], arr2[kkk:vvv], arr3[kkk:vvv]), axis=0)
                    for v in range(len(Matrix2 )):
                        for vv in range(len(Matrix2 [v])):
                            for kv in np.isclose(Matrix[i, j, z], Matrix2 [v], rtol=0.005, atol=0.0):
                                def array_for(x, y):
                                    return np.asanyarray([kv for kv in np.isclose(x[i, j, z], y[v], rtol=0.005, atol=0.0)])

                                boolarray = array_for(Matrix, Matrix2)
    
    
        if j >= 5:
            kkk += 4
            vvv += 4
            if i == 59:
                break
```

The thing i am looking to do is record data from my boolarray, into an array of the size that:

```
def array_for(x, y):
return np.asanyarray([kv for kv in np.isclose(x[i, j, z], y[v], rtol=0.005, atol=0.0)])
```

This gives me.

The size of Matrix, is 60,6,6
The size of Matrix2, is 4,72
The size of boolarray, is 4,1, for each value in Matrix

```
[False False False False]
```

i want to record the boolarray data into an array of 1,6,6,4,72
and end up with 60 of these arrays so it becomes 60,6,6,4,72

The problem i found is that numpy is memorybased arrays, and if i try and append i get a bunch of 4,1 arrays which wouldnt be able to concate either in the loop or outside the loop, with anything other than itself.

Also trying to use np.insert, will yield me the same result.

And appending data to a python list, would create wrong shapes, like haveing a shape 1,1 and inside it 72 values.

Is it possible to use this logic and if so how to achieve the desired result:

```
For values in boolarray: 
    append values a list[],
    concate with each condition like:
    if boolarray == 71:
    np.concate(values, mask)
    out = 2,4,72 
    delete mask:
    continue np.concate(value, prevvalues)
    print(Full array)

Out = 60,6,6,4,72
```

Matrix array looks like this:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5],
[2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 5, 3, 9, 5],
[4, 1, 0, 3, 8, 5],
[4, 1, 0, 3, 8, 5]]
```

Then with 60 layers of different values shown like above.

Matrix2 array looks like this:

```
 [[1, 1, 4, 5]] x72 times with different values
```

Let me know if i should explain anything further, and or if you have an idea of how to put data into an array dynamicly.
Your help is much appreciated.

Desired array should look like this:

```
[[False False False False False False],
    [False True False False False False],
    [False False True False True False],
    [False True True False True False],
    [False False False True False True ],
    [False False False False False False]] 60x times = 60,6,6

[[False True True False],
    [True True True False],
    [False False True False],
    [False True True False],
    [False False False True],
    [False False False False]] 72x times 4, 72
```

each 4 values iterates through 1 cell of 6,6 at a time, so maybe i suppose the array might look like this 72, 4, 6, 6, 1 where 1 is 1 layer out of 60

So the last is likely how it would look like, im sorry i cant represent the figure much better as it is a complex shape, compared to that of 3 dimensional object, but the Np.isclose gives this kind of relation, by 1 cell at the time. and which yield: 10,368 values in total, which is 72times,4times,6times,6,times1.

Comment: Could you provide a (reproducible) example that shows the input you have and the output you desire?

Comment: six for loops is probably not the way to go. Where is the data coming from? do you have all the input data at the start, or are you incrementally getting new data?

Comment: I made it reproducable now.

Comment: @joostblack
You might be right, the six forloops is difinitly a ruse, because that it makes it so that theres only 1 output pr iteration, therefore nothing to construct from. 

But how else would i make my code iterate controlled through everything cell wise, so that i can actually use the data. 
also if you have any ideas as to how to create a generic tuple/numpy array, i would love to hear about it. 

Best regards. 
Mathias.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
import numpy as np

#input data
Matrix = np.random.randint(5, size=(60, 6, 6))
arr = np.random.randint(5, size=(1, 240))
arr1 = np.random.randint(5, size=(1, 240))
arr2 = np.random.randint(5, size=(1, 240))
arr3 = np.random.randint(5, size=(1, 240))


# construct matrix 2
Matrix2=np.vstack((arr,arr1,arr2,arr3))

# slice matrix 2
kkk = 3
vvv = 79
Matrix2_slice=Matrix2[:,kkk:vvv]


# methods
def compare_value(x,y):
    return np.isclose(x, y, rtol=0.005, atol=0.0)

def compare_to_matrix2(x):
    return np.apply_along_axis(compare_value, 0, Matrix2_slice,x)

# output
vectorized_ctm = np.vectorize(compare_to_matrix2, signature='()->(l,p)')
output = vectorized_ctm(Matrix)

# some checks
print(output.shape)
print(output[0,0,0,0,0:10])
```

some remarks though:

- the difference between `kkk` and `vvv` is 76, not 72 so the shape is a bit different than you requested `(60,6,6,4,76)`
- `Matrix2_slice` is not used as a function input, which is not ideal
- place shift per iteration (different values for `kkk` and `vvv`) are not included

Comment: This is really awesome thanks, and mindbogling at the same time. 

I have a few questions if you dont mind. 
Yes, the vvv should have been 75, how do i check if it shifts through Matrix2_slice by the values +4 every time? 

Also the way you did the function is really cool. 
So as i understand it, it does apply the compare_value function over each cell of 'Matrix' right? because it is along the 0 axis? 
Or does it just iterate through 1 value 1 time and do the next value according with Matrix2? 
The way i intended it was to iterate over each cell 4,72 times, for all the 60,6,6 cells.

Comment: also, what is signature='()->(l,p)') in the np.vectorize function? 

It is really nice, it looks like it does exactly what i hoped to achieve with the other code, but i have many questions as to how it iterates through it, and how to check it to see whether it does like i hope it does. 

Amazing answer thanks :)

Comment: it compares all 4*72 values seperately to the one value from the `(60,6,6)` array. That is also why your output has shape `(60,6,6,72,5)`

Comment: Signature is a little hard to explain. You can read about it here:https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html. it specifies that the input is one element and the output is a 2D array.

Comment: Allright, yeah i have also played around with it, it works like a charm, Thank you so much for this joost, ive litterally spend over week trying to figure this out. 

Thanks i will check it out.

You are much apreciated.